# internalError with Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm unable to execute a query with Google Big Query. I can perform other operations (eg; listing my datasets fine). I'm authorized via Oauth2.

The POST body I'm using is (as JSON):

```
{
  "kind" => "bigquery#queryRequest",
  "query" => "SELECT day,sum(clicks) as clicks FROM [dc.test_data] where group by day   order by day desc LIMIT 10;",
  "defaultDataset" => {
  "datasetId" => "dc"
}
```

I'm getting back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "internalError",
        "message": "Unexpected. Please try again."
      }
    ],
    "code": 503,
    "message": "Unexpected. Please try again."
  }
}
```

Changing the query doesn't seem to make ANY difference. I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default dataset is missing a projectId. This shouldn't be needed -- we should re-use the project id from the query, but right now the consistency checking is over-zealous and tries to enforce that all references are fully-specified. I've filed an internal bug and it should almost certainly be fixed in our release next week.

In the mean-time, you can either remove the default dataset section (since it looks like your dataset is specified in the query) or add a projectId to the default dataset.